# Cisco AnyConnect VPN client adding 'WWW' to local domain?

Tags: vpn, domain-name, split-tunnel, cisco-anyconnect

My workstation (a Windows 10 machine) is part of a local domain. One of my local web applications connects as: http://[MachineName].[DomainName]/blablah.html and I can't seem to simply make it as http://localhost/blahblah.html to work. BTW, the domain is NOT a Fully Qualified Domain Name (FQDN).

Once I use a Cisco AnyConnect Client (4.6) to VPN to a remote server then the local web page is forced by the VPN connection to go to http://www.[MachineName].[DomainName].blahblah.html page--which of course doesn't work. Do note that the http://localhost still works and I am still able to connect to local machines etc.

Is there any way around it? I think part of the problem is that a local web application wants to go through the URL of [MachineName].[DomainName] and part of the problem is that Cisco VPN connection, once it sees the Domain in the URL, it forces a 'www' in the front.

Thank you!

Comment: Thanks. I have a omitting the domain, tried Localhost instead (which should be the same as IP address of localhost) but one specific application is configured to only work when there is MACHINENAME.DOMAIN name is in the URL.

Comment: Go to `Internet Options` > `General` tab, `Languages` button, and then in the `Language Preference` windows, check the option that states **Do not add 'www' to the beginning of typed web addresses** and see if that helps resolve the problem with Internet Explorer as the web browers.

Comment: Thanks. Will do so. BTW, sorry to answer late: Browser is FireFox.

Comment: Other solutions are here for FF: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10186383/browsers-adding-www-and-com-to-server-address-automatically although I tested some and got mixed results so not 100% certain with FF for that sort of fix.

Comment: In case of IE, no 'www' was added automatically. In case of FF, I followed that link to S.O and did help in not prepending the 'www' to the url--but same results in both IE and FF despite these: The local web application still wouldn't load when I have the Cisco VPN. So probably something else is going on. Thanks for your help! I learned some new things.